# Meromorphic function with infinitely many poles must have essential singularity at point of infinity?

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity, meromorphic-functions

**Question:** Suppose $f: \mathbb{C}\setminus P \to \mathbb{C}$ is *meromorphic* on the complex plane, where $P:=\{z_n: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a set of infinitely many isolated poles with $\infty$ as their only limit point on the extended complex plane. With this condition, can we conclude $f$ has essential sigularity at $\infty$?

I'm know if we require $f$ to be meromorphic on the *extended* complex plane, then there are at most finitely many poles, where $\infty$ can be either a removeable singularity or a pole. Since then $f$ must be holomorphic on $|z|>R$ for some $R>0$ and its complement is a compact set. But for a function to be meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$, it doesn't matter how it behaves at $\infty$, and nothing prevents it from having a sequence of poles diverging to $\infty$. Hence the question. Thanks.

Comment: it really depends on the meaning of singularity - if poles are considered singularities then $\infty$ is not an isolated singularity as the poles accumulate there, but if poles are considered regular (maybe in the extended sense of allowing infinity as a value) points, then yes infinity is essential with the proof mentioned in the OP

Answer (score 1):

If a meromorphic function $f(z)$ does not have essential singularity at $z=\infty$, then the principal part of the Laurent expansion of $f(w^{-1})$ at $w=0$ only contains finitely many terms. That is, there is some $R>0$ such that when $|w|<R^{-1}$, there is some $N\in\mathbb N$ such that

$$
f(w^{-1})=\sum_{n\ge1}b_nw^n+a_0+a_1w^{-1}+\dots+a_Nw^{-N}.
$$

In other words, for $|z|>R$, there is

$$
f(z)=\sum_{n\ge1}b_nz^{-n}+a_0+a_1z+\dots+a_Nz^N.
$$

This indicates that $f$ has no poles other than $z=\infty$ for $|z|>R$. Furthermore, because $f$ is meromorphic, it can only possess finitely many poles in $|z|<R$, so we conclude that

**Proposition 1:** *If $f$ is meromorphic in $\mathbb C$ and at $\infty$, then it can only possess finitely many poles.*

Because essential singularity needs to be isolated, the contrapositive of this proposition is

**Proposition 2:** *If $f$ is meromorphic in $\mathbb C$ and has infinitely many poles, then $z=\infty$ is a singularity of $f$ that is not isolated.*